# Negative tag score == positive badge progress?

Tags: bug, badge-progress, tag-score

I have seen a user with a negative tag score but the score progress of the tag badge is displayed positively.

This is the tag the user wrote most answers about so I understand why it is displayed as the next tag badge.

[image: Next tag badge with negative score]

This raises the following questions:

- Why is the score displayed as positive progress?
- <del>Is it (theoretically) possible to receive a tag badge when having a negative tag score?</del>

I think this is a bug that should be fixed.

Comment: `Is it (theoretically) possible to receive a tag badge when having a negative tag score?` I found out that there is actually a user on Meta who has more than 20 answers on a tag with a tag score of less than `-100` and he does not have this badge.

Comment: This is a quite impressive accomplishment, this deserves a tag on its own :)

Comment: Yes, but that should be at least a gold tag. Unfortunately, all users who accomplished this on meta are suspended and no one accomplished this on stackoverflow (I am using the Data Explorer in order to find that out).

Comment: Poop tag badge: Earn -100 or more tag score in at least 20 non-Community Wiki answers. Answers that were deleted as spam or offensive do not count.

Comment: Should that be a bronze badge @RobertColumbia

Comment: There are two users here on meta and no users on StackOverflow who achieved this. This is at least s gold badge.

Comment: @dan1st ... but the brownish colour of bronze would make sense...

Comment: Yeah, ok. We should let the designers come up with the worst solution...like always...we cannot even do anything against it.

Comment: @dan1st For this comment, you should get the "Knows how Stackexchange really works"-tag

Comment: This is not only how stackexchange works, this is how the world works. Stackexchange just follows this.

Comment: @dan1st The key difference is that the world is totally transparent about this, there are no misleading statements like "We don’t run Stack Overflow. You do." or "It's built and run by you"

Comment: And `<SE site> is moderated by you`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick tweak of the CSS resolves this issue:

[image]

I changed the `min-width` from 6px to 0px to remove the non-present progress.